# stop unknown instance for mysql

Tags: mysql

I have to reset a mySQL root password but when I try to run this command:

```
sudo stop mysql
```

and it outputs: stop unknown instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your shell thinks `stop` is a program. Instead you should run :

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```